# Select block order by timestamp and randomized by id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a huge data base containing more then 500k rows, I want to select the first 1000 IDs orderd by timestamp and then shuffle the result. Php `shuffle()` is somehow to memory expensive or to slow for that. I want to try it now in MySQL database. Is it possible? What are the alternatives? I also implemented a limit and offset to realize paging, so what I want to do is in short words to get the page and shuffle the results.

How can I do it in SQL or actually I like to use Codeigniters active record.

```
ID, | timestamp, | data...
--------------------------
 0  | 2014-00-.. | some data..
 1  | 1987-00-.. | .
 .  | 2004-00-.. | .
 .  | 1546-00-.. | .
```

Comment: There is a way using rand() i.e. you first select data and a rand() value for each row then order by timestamp and then order by rand, but rand() is not good for the queries.

Comment: As a first note... when I subset data randomly, I try to avoid first and last with any order. Having an ID column, and wanting a 1/500 subset, I'd use an (ID % 500)=0 condition... that typically guarantees a quite random extraction.

Comment: @Frazz: However, that depends upon ID column having no gaps and yet would still require a *full table scan*.

Comment: As for random ordering... client-side you say php has its problems... but server-side it is doomed to make the engine build some temporary table... probably not very efficient.

Comment: It would require a full table scan, but it does not depend on gaps. Unless there is a correlation between gaps and how the data has been inserted, the modulus operator on an autoinc column is the best way to extract unskewed data.

Comment: it should not be such extensive because I wan't the random just on the block of e.g. 1000 ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 1000
) as a ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: I accept it but a codeigniter solution would be also nice, as I don't know how to transform this to active record request.

Comment: @abimelex: I have no experience with codeigniter i'm afraid.

Comment: no problem I just want to say if a solution with codeigniter cames up, O would mark this as correct answer.